# Normal distribution: how to find the mean $µ$ and standard deviation $σ$?

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution, standard-deviation, means

A random variable $X$ is normally distributed with mean $µ$ and standard deviation $σ$.

lf $P(X < 25)$ is $0.1082$ and $P(X> 42)$ is $0.1303$ determine:

> (i) $P(25 < X < 42)$
>
> (ii) the values of mean $µ$ and standard deviation $σ$
>
> (iii) $P(X>22)$

For part (i), I have done $P(25 < X < 42) = P(X<42) - P(X<25)$ which gives $(1-0.1303)-0.1082 = 0.7615$.

I'm unsure how to do part (ii). I'm thinking it has something to do with the empirical rule, so $68.3\%$ lies within one standard deviation of the mean, etc. But I'm not sure how to apply this, as there doesn't seem to be any concrete "percent rule" that the $0.7615$ applies to. This is from a high school maths textbook. Any hints would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In normal distribution we use the notation $P(X\le a)=\phi(a)$

$P\bigg(\dfrac{x-\mu}{\sigma} < \dfrac {25-\mu}{\sigma}\bigg)=P\bigg(Z< \dfrac {25-\mu}{\sigma}\bigg)=\phi\bigg(\dfrac{25-\mu}{\sigma}\bigg)=0.1082$

Now look at normal table and find $a$ such that $\phi(a)=0.1082$ then,

$a=\dfrac{25-\mu}{\sigma}$

similarly, you have $P(X>42)=.1303$

So you will get two equations two unknows$(\mu$ and $\sigma)$ solve them you will get $
\mu,\sigma$

Comment: I do not understand - so I have these standardised scores $z1 = \frac{25-µ}{σ}$ and $z2 = \frac{42-µ}{σ}$...do I solve these with simultaneous equations? What am I substituting in?

Comment: @user780357 you have to find $a$ from normal tables. Do you know how to read normal probability tables?Can you tell me what is $a$ in this case: $P(Z<a)=0.5$

Comment: for my exams I'm not given a normal probability table. I have to use a calculator function but I don't know what equation with the unknown values I'm supposed to be solving

Comment: For what value of Z probability is $0.1082$?

Comment: I got $-1.236157567$...is that correct?

Comment: The answer given is mean = $33.9$ and SD = $7.2$

Comment: @user780357 Yes, now equate $-1.236=\dfrac{25-\mu}{\sigma}$ similarly you have find the value of $Z$ for which $P(X>42)=0.1303 \implies P(X <42) = 1-0.1303$ ...two equations and two unknowns $\mu$ and $\sigma$

Comment: oh, I see - I got the answer now thank you!